# Google Or-Tools : UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, spring, or-tools

I have created a spring application which uses google or-tools. For that, I am importing jniortools using System.loadLibrary("jniortools"). when I provide the .dll file and run the war file it runs perfectly. But when I provide the .so file path in lib, I get the unsatisfiedlinkerror.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62209117/887343), a solution for using or-tools over Intellij:

To make it work using Intellij (over a windows machine) you need to:

1. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=Visual%20C%2B%2B%20Redistributable%20for%20Visual%20Studio)
2. Download and extract the [OR-Tools library for Java](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/download/v7.6/or-tools_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v7.6.7691.zip)
3. In intellij, [add jar dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853178/887343) to the 2 jars under the lib folder of the extracted files (each of the 2 jars separately, do not add to lib folder itself. [This is why](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000123070/comments/115000159710)).
4. Add the lib library path to VM options. In Intellij edit your run-configuration and add to vm options: `-Djava.library.path=<path to the lib folder that hold the jars>`
5. Load the jni library statically by adding the below code to your class (as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/YuYly4-h3kM).)

   `static {
       System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
   }`